# Error while trying to restart debezium mysql connector after restarting the db

Tags: java, mysql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

MySql ROW level binloging in enabled.

```
ERROR Failed to start the connector (see other exception), but got this error while cleaning up (io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask:183)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.stop(MySqlConnectorTask.java:220)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:180)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:141)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ERROR Task lk-mysql-connector-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:141)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: io.debezium.text.ParsingException: Expecting token type 128 at line 1, column 1 but found 'DELETE':  ===>> DELETE from mysql.rd
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:141)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: io.debezium.text.ParsingException: Expecting token type 128 at line 1, column 1 but found 'DELETE':  ===>> DELETE from mysql.rd
        at io.debezium.text.TokenStream.consume(TokenStream.java:737)
        at io.debezium.relational.ddl.DdlParser.consumeStatement(DdlParser.java:568)
        at io.debezium.relational.ddl.DdlParser.parseUnknownStatement(DdlParser.java:376)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlDdlParser.parseNextStatement(MySqlDdlParser.java:156)
        at io.debezium.relational.ddl.DdlParser.parse(DdlParser.java:286)
        at io.debezium.relational.ddl.DdlParser.parse(DdlParser.java:267)
        at io.debezium.relational.history.AbstractDatabaseHistory.lambda$recover$0(AbstractDatabaseHistory.java:57)
        at io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory.recoverRecords(KafkaDatabaseHistory.java:202)
        at io.debezium.relational.history.AbstractDatabaseHistory.recover(AbstractDatabaseHistory.java:52)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.loadHistory(MySqlSchema.java:312)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlTaskContext.loadHistory(MySqlTaskContext.java:116)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:80)
        ... 8 more
```

Comment: Can you check that the [binlog format](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/#configuration) is set to "row"? If it is, was is it set to another value perhaps previously?

Comment: Yes, previously it was set to MIXED. But if that is the case it should fail on start up itself, it is happening for me when mysql is restarted and while trying to restart debezium again to connect to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to debezium 0.5.2, it was an acknowledged issue for RDS and they fixed it:

http://debezium.io/docs/releases/

https://issues.jboss.org/projects/DBZ/issues/DBZ-216?filter=allissues